# Перенос строки \n

Tags: php

Почему то не работает любая форма записи.
    echo "Строка 1 nr";
    echo "строка 2";

```
echo "Строка 1 \r\n";
echo "строка 2";

echo "Строка 1 \n\n";
echo "строка 2";

echo "Строка 1 \n\";
echo "строка 2";
```

Comment: Всмысле не работает? Какой результат вы хотитето?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы делаете, вы считываете PHP - файл программой на С# или вы отправляете HTTP - запрос к этому файлу?

Comment: И не забываем про http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php и PHP_EOL

Answer (score 6):

```
echo "Hello\n"; //перенос строки текст "как есть", если посмотреть исходный код страницы в браузере, то перенос будет заметен там
echo 'Hello<br />'; //перенос строки в HTML, если смотреть не исходный HTML, а обработанный, то перенос будет именно в ней
```

Не путайте перенос строки с новой строкой, вот ещё пример :

```
echo "\n\n"; //если выполнить этот код, а результат записать в файл, то любой текстовый редактор вам скажет, что здесь есть минимум две строки
echo '<br /><br />'; //а если сделать то же самое с этим кодом, то тут будет всего одна строка по мнению текстового редактора
```

Comment: ps: `\n` не модно, `PHP_EOL` рулит.

Answer (score 4):

Вывод-то куда происходит? Если HTML в браузер - то `<br>`, если в консоль или файл - `\n`

Answer (score 1):

```
может где чего-то настроить надо?
```

**шутите? =)**

Попробуйте так:

```
echo "Строка 1 <br>";
echo "строка 2";

echo "Строка 1<br><br>";
echo "строка 2";

echo "Строка 1 ";
echo "строка 2";
```

А вообще интересно знать, что у вас конкретно не работает. Все работает)

Comment: я через C# получаю код html страницы, мне нужно перенести строку без <br>, если это возможно

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите исходный код. Всё работает, я видел.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно ставить `header` в начало кода:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
echo "раз ...\n";
echo "два ...\n";
echo "три ...\n";
```